# How to find and edit custom endpoints. In wordpress rest apis

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using this WooCommerce Rest API to get products for my mobile app.

I use this API "wp-json/wc/v3/products/344" to get a product.

On response I got below objects:

```
{ id: 5, name: test}
```

I can't find where I have to change it on WooCommerce folder.

How can I put this objects into an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert JSON Object to Array in php you can do it by using `json_decode()` function like this.

```
$data = json_decode('{ "id": 5, "name": "test"}',true);
print_r($data);
```

**output**

```
 Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => test )
```

**But**

your JSON responce `{ id: 5, name: test}`  is not valid.Valid JSON strings have quoted keys:

```
//fails
json_decode('{ id: 5, name: test}'); 

//return array Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => test )
json_decode('{ "id": 5, "name": "test"}', true); 

// returns an object stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [name] => test)
json_decode('{ "id": 5, "name": "test"}');
```

Comment: i just need something like this :[ { "id":5, "name": "Test"}]. I want to known where i have to change it on WooCommerce folder.

Comment: I dont know much about wp but i suggest you to please check theme and plugin folders inside wp-content folder and also check function.php file of current activated theme.One more thing please change your question heading to something like this (How to find and edit custom endpoints wordpress rest api)